# Spark/Java NoClassDefFoundError when adding dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I'm starting from the examples in the Spark distribution (v1.6.2). I added my own "Hello World" example and that worked fine. Trying to add something that uses a 3rd party dependency (com.google.cloud:gcloud-java-nio:0.2.5), here is what happens:

> 16/07/22 13:05:26 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught
>   exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-7,5,main]
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/spark-project/guava/base/MoreObjects  at
>   com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.activeGoogleCloudConfig(ServiceOptions.java:282)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.googleCloudProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:294)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.defaultProject(ServiceOptions.java:270)
>     at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.(ServiceOptions.java:206)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.HttpServiceOptions.(HttpServiceOptions.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.(StorageOptions.java:69)
>   (...)

I ran my code as follows:

```
spark-1.6.2$ mvn -DskipTests clean package
(lots of time passes...)
spark-1.6.2$ ./bin/run-example JavaGcsTest
```

And to add the dependency I added those lines to `examples/pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>gcloud-java-nio</artifactId>
<version>0.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It looks like the root cause is that both gcloud-java-nio and Spark depend on guava, and perhaps they depend on different versions of it.

I looked at related questions and the answers suggest making a fat jar. I'm not sure how to apply this here, though, as examples are already bundled into a fat jar (`examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.6.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar`).

I tried changing the version of guava that was used, raising it from 14 to 19 (the latest), but of course then the compilation failed (SparkEnv.scala:84: method softValues in class MapMaker cannot be accessed in com.google.common.collect.MapMaker).

Hopefully someone has advice on how to get Spark to work with this 3rd party library!

Answer (score 0):

A way to get out of this problem is to compile a shaded version of the third-party library and use that jar as the dependency.

In the case of gcloud-java-nio the project already includes a shaded jar target so after running `mvn package` it's in `target/gcloud-java-nio-0.2.7-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`.